# Line break in email message in expression engine 2

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

I have a script that sends email to the user that want to register in our website when i am sending email it does not recognize the line break ("\r \n"). suggest a solution

**code**

```
$to = $workemail;
$subject = 'REGISTRATION SUBMISSION';
$message = 'Thank you for submitting \n your request to register ';

ee()->load->library('email');
ee()->load->helper('text');
ee()->email->set_newline("\r\n");
ee()->email->wordwrap = false;
ee()->email->mailtype = 'text';
ee()->email->from("info@abc.com");
ee()->email->to($to);
ee()->email->subject($subject);
ee()->email->message($message);
ee()->email->Send();
```

**email output**

```
Thank you for submitting n your request to register
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ee()->email->mailtype = 'html'; instead?